# outbound ports as listed by netstat don't match the ports described by IETF

Tags: networking, https

I have learned that https protocol is served on port 443, and that this means that my request is routed over outbound port 443 towards inbound port 443 of the target webserver.
However when I try to verify this with a simple command:

```
netstat -q
```

output:

proto -- local adres -- foreign adress -- state

Tcp -- 10.10.1.19:52295 - stackoverflow.com:https -- ESTABLISHED

It's not just stackoverflow, other websites behave the same. What am I missing here? Why is it not 10.10.1.19:443? A classmate of mine had similar results so I don't think it has to do with special configuration on my end.

Comment: "_I have learned that https protocol is served on port 443, and that this means that my request is routed over outbound port 443 towards inbound port 443 of the target webserver._" No, you misunderstand. Your outbound port will vary because it is a randomly chosen ephemeral port. The server inbound port _will_ be port 443, but your outbound port will not be 443.

Comment: @Ron Maupin thanks for pointing out the concept of ephemeral ports. I wasn't aware of those yet.